# Apply a function for each row according to its column's number

Tags: r

3I have this function:

```
nombre_points<-function(typeAction)
{
  if(typeAction==1)
  {return(4)}
  else if (typeAction==2)
  {return(3)}
  else if (typeAction==3)
  {return(2)}
}
```

And I want to applicate it to each columns of a data frame

```
df>
ID 1 2 3
XX 0 1 2
YY 1 2 3
EE 2 2 1 
ZZ 0 3 4
```

I want to applicate the above function to this data frame where the input of the
`nombre_points` function is the column's number.

So as result I need to get for each row a data frame like this:

```
df>

    ID Result
    XX 7
    YY 14
    EE 16
    ZZ 17
```

In fact for the observation ZZ for example `17=0*4+3*3+4*2`
also for the XX observation we have a score :`7=0*4+3*1+2*2`

I tried to used `apply` function :

```
dd<-apply(df,1,nombre_points)
```

But it doesn't give the needed result

Comment: Read about `ifelse`.

Comment: @zx8754, How about the `nombre_points` function ?? it has as input the number of column.

Comment: Are you still sure about the calculation? Shouldn't `XX` be 7 ? `(0 * 4) + (1 * 3) + (2 * 2)`  ? `YY` and `EE` also requires update I think.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes y're right, I just correct it

Comment: @SA2018 I have updated the answer, please have a look. PS - Value of `YY` should be `(1 * 4) + (2 * 3) + (3 * 2) = 16` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Since, the values might not be related to column number we can create a named vector or a lookup dataframe to get the corresponding values.

With lookup table :

```
named_df <- data.frame(col = c(1, 2, 3), value = c(4, 3, 2))
rowSums(df[-1] * named_df$value[col(df[-1])])
#[1]  7 16 16 17
```

With named vector :

```
named_vec <- c("1" = 4, "2" = 3, "3" = 2)
rowSums(named_vec[col(df[-1])] * df[-1])
#[1]  7 16 16 17
```

The logic for both the approach is the same , we match the column number with the name of `named_vec` or `col` of `named_df` and get the corresponding value and then multiply it with the actual value in the dataframe and then take sum of each row using `rowSums`.

**Original Answer**

You could multiply each value in the dataframe with it's column number - 1 to get your desired result. Here, `df[-1]` is to ignore the first column (`ID`).

```
df$result <- rowSums(df[-1] * (col(df) - 1))
df

#  ID X1 X2 X3 result
#1 XX  0  1  2      5
#2 YY  1  2  3      8
#3 EE  2  2  1      4
#4 ZZ  0  3  4     11
```

For understanding purposes `col(df)` gives

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
#[3,]    1    2    3    4
#[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: how about if the function is general ? look at the edit question please. the example that I give is just to make it simple, but in reality I work with more complex data

Comment: @SA2018 Can you check your calculation again? What do you want to do for column 3 then?